# Stored Procedure Returning Selected values

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables in a database. One is `Group` table and the other is `Status` table. Both have GroupId common. So I will inner join them I will get all the records. Status table has status column in the table, that status column has 6 values like

```
1)  active
2)  not active
3)  pending
4)  approved
5)  placed
6)  unplaced
```

Now all the records has one column related to status column..

I need a stored procedure that will get the records like if it is active we will get the record on inner joining both tables, if it is placed status we will get the placed column records and so on, if user doesn't select anything we will get all records. This I will bind to dropdown list and those values will be displayed in gridview in front end.

This is my code:

```
create procedure Sp_SelectedStatus 
@Status varchar(20) as 
Begin 
if(@Status = 'Active') 
    Begin 
    Select A.GroupName , B.Brand , B.Model , 
           B.SerialNo , B.Status , B.AddedOn 
    from GroupDetails as A 
    inner join DeviceDetails as B 
    on A.GroupId = B.GroupId 
    where Status = 'Active' 
    End
End
```

Comment: Couple of things. Adding table schema in tabular format and desired result to the question would have saved you lots of typing. Also, please show what you have tried.

Comment: --if status = Active
select a.GroupName,b.Brand,b.model,b.serialno , b.Status from status b 
inner join Group a 
on a.GroupId = b.GroupId where Status = 'Active'

Comment: I am trying by If exists show else no..

Comment: Have you written any SQL? Even `SELECT * From Table`? Please post it

Comment: create procedure Sp_SelectedStatus 
@Status varchar(20)
as 
Begin

              if(@Status = 'Active')
              Begin
              Select A.GroupName , B.Brand , B.Model , B.SerialNo , B.Status ,B.AddedOn from 
              GroupDetails as A
              inner join 
              DeviceDetails as B
              on A.GroupId = B.GroupId where Status = 'Active'
              End

Comment: I will add this code for you. In future please edit your original question and add it (note I added a missing END)

Comment: Now you've posted your cod,e what is the problem? an error? incorrect result?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided, this could be a possible stored procedure. "if user doesn't select anything we will get all records" - defaulted the @Status variable to null, this makes it optional, and the query will then return all records.

```
create procedure dbo.usp_GetStatus 
    @Status varchar(20) = null 
AS 

SET NOCOUNT ON;

Select G.GroupName, D.Brand, D.Model, D.SerialNo, D.[Status], D.AddedOn 
from GroupDetails as G inner join 
    DeviceDetails as D on G.GroupId = D.GroupId 
where D.Status = IsNull(@Status, D.Status);
```